# Artifactory OSS LDAP - test success, but login denied

Tags: authentication, ldap, artifactory, access-denied

we are using Artifactory OSS version 5.10.4 (I know it is old), with LDAP authentication to Active Directory. We add additional(new) LDAP Active Directory authentication source, test account works well, but we cannot login, we get access denied in access.log and username/password incorrect on the login page. I have no idea what could be wrong. No error or message in artifactory.log.

We tried changing manager account format. Always the test is successfull, but login is denied.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up LDAP is not enough to grant access to Artifactory.

It is necessary to configure an LDAP-Group, linking previously configured LDAP and adding the right filters to point to a certain Organization Unit (LDAP dir).

Finally, you will need to create an Artifactory Group of type External that points to one (or +) of the groups present within the LDAP OU we are targeting.

This will be used to be able to attach the Permissions necessary for your users to the Local Groups (pointing to LDAP groups).

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/LDAP (for these concepts, it doesn't matter whether the version of Artifactory is 5.x or 7.x)

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=46107586#LDAPGroups-SynchronizingLDAPGroupswithArtifactory

Comment: I would like to add a few more documentation and youtube links to the above information. 
https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-configure-ldap-with-tls-in-aritfactory/

Youtube Screencast : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nT76RgXA2c

https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-troubleshoot-ldap-configuration/